# Handlebar Expression to Iterate over object Arrays

Tags: node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I have a requirment where I have to Iterate over two array of objects using handlebar helper.

Suppose I have data something like this

```
{
  people: [
    "Aman",
    "Ashok",
    "Ashley",
  ],
  Animals: [
   "Panda",
   "Tiger",
   "Lion"
  ]
}
```

The output using handlebar helper should come like this

Aman, Panda
Ashok, Tiger
Ashley, Lion

If I use below expression all the values in Animals are getting printed for each people value.

```
 <class="people_list">
  {{#each people}}
{{../Animals}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

How do I Iterate over each value of Animals and people array seperately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) helper for this purpose:

```
<ui class="people_list">
  {{#each people}}
    <li>{{this}}, {{lookup ../Animals @index}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```